# incomprehensible behavior of the for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I have really strange problem... I'm trying to create plots in a loop and put them to the list and after that drew them all on one page. when I do it:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){ 
   plot[[i]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,i], y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
     geom_bar(fill="#003366") + 
     labs(title = dfcolnames[i], x = "Variable Values", y = "Frequency") 
}
return(multiplot(plotlist=plot, cols = 2))
```

I get 3 this same plots, but when I do it without for loop:

```
plot[[1]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,1], y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + geom_bar(fill="#003366") + labs(title = dfcolnames[1], x = "Variable Values", y = "Frequency")
plot[[2]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,2], y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + geom_bar(fill="#003366") + labs(title = dfcolnames[2], x = "Variable Values", y = "Frequency") 
plot[[3]] <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df[,3], y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + geom_bar(fill="#003366") + labs(title = dfcolnames[3], x = "Variable Values", y = "Frequency") 
return(multiplot(plotlist=plot, cols = 2))
```

I get correct plots (three different). I don't understand what is going on.... Any ideas?

Comment: You should read `ggplot2` tutorial on how to plot wide/long data and fill bars by variable instead of creating three different plots.

Comment: but what is wrong with loop that i created?

Comment: Not sure - works fine for me when I replace `df` with `mtcars`. But you're really not using `ggplot` the way it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `aes()` performs lazy evaluation. The values you pass to `aes()` are only resolved when you actually draw the plot. You really should only be passing symbol names to `aes()`. This is because after the loop ends, `i` will be fixed at it's last value from the loop and you'll just get the same plot three times.

You could instead use `aes_string` and loop over the column names

```
plot <- lapply(names(df), function(colname) {
  ggplot(df, aes_string(x = colname, y="(..count..)/sum(..count..)")) + 
           geom_bar(fill="#003366") + 
           labs(title = colname, x = "Variable Values", y = "Frequency") 
})
```

Tested with

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(a=rpois(100, 5), b=rpois(100, 7), c=rpois(100, 3))
```

Comment: You solved my problem, thank you!